# How to create a list of Tab from a list of String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to improve the following code snippet  by removing the hard coded number `5` (the number of elements in the list). How to do so?

```
child: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              ...List.generate(
                5,
                (i) => Tab(
                  child: Text([
                    'Text',
                    'Icons',
                    'Images',
                    'Simple Form',
                    'Proper Form'
                  ][i]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Use `map` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
tabs:
  'Text/Icons/Images/Simple Form/Proper Form'.split('/').
    map((e) => Tab(child: Text(e)).toList();
```

Comment: I made it easier to type.  Look again!

Comment: Yes. A great improvement. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's simple.

Define your list of Strings as the main source for your interface, iterate over it and create the Tab widgets.

```dart
TabBar(
  tabs: [
          'Text',
          'Icons',
          'Images',
          'Simple Form',
          'Proper Form'
        ].map(
          (tabName) => Tab(child: Text(tabName))
        ).toList()
)
```